# How should I manage my investments if I plan to remain single?

Tags: investing, india

I am 22 y/o male living in India. I plan to remain single for the rest of my life. I'll begin earning by at most next year. How should I plan my investments? What are some things I should consider?

For example, I see no point for an life insurance, as no one is/would be dependent on me. But a health insurance makes sense.

Similarly, too much long term investment seems unproductive, but what would be too much?

So I'd like some suggestions for managing the investments/money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Similarly, too much long term investment seems unproductive, but what would be too much?

In 1900, the life expectancy of someone in the United States was less than 50.  It is now in the 70s.  My grandparents were born around that time and all lived into their 80s and 90s.  Life expectancy in India is currently about 66.  You should expect that to increase into the 70s if not the 80s in the next fifty years.

You should plan on living until 120.  Why?  If you die earlier than that, you may have wasted some money that you could have used for a better living standard.  However, if you do live that long and you spent all your savings by the time that you were 66, you'll have a hard retirement.  You've already said that you won't have descendants to take care of you.  You'll need your investments to do so.  You need long term investments more than someone with a family, not less.

You need to able to afford a house for retirement.  You need to be able to maintain it, buy food, etc. on your savings.  In order to be sure it lasts, you need to build your long term investments until they produce a steady income that comes close to matching your preretirement income.

There are some costs that you won't have in retirement.  You won't need to save for retirement.  You won't need to commute to work.  So your retirement income doesn't need to support that.

If I were you, I'd save like everyone else until income from investments matched my current expenses minus commuting.  At that time, you can readjust.

Overall, you are far more likely not to save enough than too much.  I wouldn't worry about oversaving in your twenties.  No one actually does so.

Answer (score 0):

At your young age, the most of your wealth is your future labor income (unless you are already rich).

Your most profitable investment at this time is most likely to be investment in your human capital (your professional skills, career opportunities).

Depending on how you plan to earn your money, invest time and effort to enable you to earn better wages in that activity. So focus on education or professional training.

Also, consider that it is probably your total lifetime utility/welfare you should maximize (but you decide!). I suggest you do not focus narrowly on earning as much money as possible. Consider what sort of life you want and what you need to do to enable it.

Best of luck!